# No mailboxes in gmail, using php imap for pop3

Tags: php, html, email, imap, pop3

I'm trying to fetch emails from gmail using PHP IMAP, but doing it with POP3.
It's kinda working, but I'm trying to get the mailboxes and all I get with `imap_list` is `{pop.gmail.com:995/pop3/ssl}INBOX`
I've looked everywhere but can't find out what's wrong. Also `pop.gmail.com` won't connect to any mailbox except `INBOX`.

How could I get a list of mailboxes and connect to a specific one?

Relevant code:

```
$server = "{".$acc_Server.":995/pop3/ssl}";
$mail = imap_open($server, $acc_Email, $acc_Pass);
$mailboxes = imap_list($mail, $server, '*');
print_r($mailboxes);
```

Result:

`Array ( [0] => {pop.gmail.com:995/pop3/ssl}INBOX )`

Comment: POP3 will always only give you access to what's in the inbox, only. If you want to access subfolders (= GMail labels), you need to connect using IMAP. See [Google's information page](https://support.google.com/mail/troubleshooter/1668960?hl=en) on the topic. Also, the IMAP server address for GMail is `imap.gmail.com`.

Comment: @nhee Thanks for the information! Though i am a bit shy about IMAP, I've successfully deleted all my messages using that once so i'm a bit nervous using that with my thing... Thank you though!

Comment: Ok. Please google "php IMAP gmail" and you will find loads of tutorials and open source solutions to this problem.